# How *not* to show the last post on the latest posts list

Tags: posts, php, functions

An image speaks for a thousand words so please bear with me:
http://interativo.modateca-sc.com/

The last post appears twice. Once as the feature post and then again on the "main blog part" where the ten or so latest posts appear. Is there a way to make it not appear again?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the code of "Main blog part", loop.php i guess... or any code your theme uses..

Find get_posts and use exclude parameter to exclude the post from there. Pass id of featured post as exclude...

Here is reference...

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts